# Deprecated Ecto.DateTime casting with newer version of Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an older version of Elixir code which use `Ecto.DateTime.cast()`. However since the release of Ecto 3.x, `Ecto.DateTime` is deprecated. I have the following code and I'm wondering how to convert to the latest version.

schema `inserted_at` returns `~N[2019-01-11 09:55:34]`

**code:**

```elixir
{:ok, inserted_at} = media.inserted_at |> Ecto.DateTime.cast()
```

returns the warning and I think it is time to change this deprecated code.

**Error**

```elixir
warning: Ecto.DateTime.cast/1 is undefined (module Ecto.DateTime is not available or is yet to be defined)

warning: Ecto.Date.cast/1 is undefined (module Ecto.Date is not available or is yet to be defined)
```

I have another function which is uses Date as well and that returns warning as well.

```elixir
  def parse_media_date(params, key) do
    case params[key] |> Timex.parse("{YYYY}-{0M}-{0D}") do
      {:ok, date} ->
        {:ok, date} = Ecto.Date.cast(date)
        %{params | key => date}

      {:error, _reason} ->
        params
    end
  end
```

Since Elixir's `DateTime` doesn't have a `cast()` function, what is the best way to change this code to the current version of `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `inserted_at` definition in your schema to [`:naive_datetime`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-primitive-types), then you should be able to remove the call to `Ecto.DateTime.cast()`, because Ecto will convert it to a [`NaiveDateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html) for you automatically.

You can also use `:utc_datetime` to get a `DateTime`, but this will be a change in behaviour compared to your existing code.

Comment: Currently schema “media” do ….. ```timestamps(usec: false)``` end. Do I need to change this?

Comment: Ah ok. No I don't think so, just remove the `Ecto.DateTime.cast()` call.